# How to prevent quitting from inner preference screen when there's a configuration change

Tags: android

I have the following preference screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <PreferenceCategory 
        android:title="@string/preference_about">
        <PreferenceScreen
            android:title="@string/preference_backup_restore_data"
            android:persistent="false">
            <Preference
                android:key="BACKUP"
                android:title="@string/preference_backup" />
            <Preference
                android:key="RESTORE"
                android:title="@string/preference_restore" />
        </PreferenceScreen>
        <Preference
            android:key="FAQ"
            android:title="@string/preference_faq_title" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

If I went into the inner preference screen by tapping `preference_backup_restore_data`, and rotate my device, I will quit from the inner preference screen.

I was wondering, how can I prevent such behavior? I prefer to stay in inner preference screen, even though there is configuration change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `android:key` to `PreferenceScreen` will able to handle configuration change nicely.

Instead of

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="@string/preference_backup_restore_data"
    android:persistent="false">
```

Use

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="PREFERENCE_BACKUP_RESTORE_DATA"
    android:title="@string/preference_backup_restore_data"
    android:persistent="false">
```